# redis-benchmark fails to get CONFIG

Tags: redis

ERROR: failed to fetch CONFIG from 127.0.0.1:6379
WARNING: Could not fetch server CONFIG

It looks like, it requires certs in order to connect with Redis Instance.

I dont see TLS options in redis-benchmark help menu ???

Any idea on how to build/compile redis-benchmark with TLS options enabled

Answer (score 1):

The version of redis that I use 6.0.5 doesn't have TLS option for redis-benchmark and it was introduced in https://github.com/redis/redis/releases/tag/6.2-rc1.